# How to tell if a function argument is an immediate?

Tags: c, gcc, ld, gnu-assembler

I have an inline function definition that wraps an inline assembly.  I wish to choose
different inline assembly implementation based on the fact whether or not the argument
is known in build time or not.

My question is how to ask in C code or inline assembly whether an **address** value is an known at build time and therefore fit to be an immediate value. If you are thinking __builtin_constant_p - please do read ahead.

Here is a bit of code that illustrates my intent:. I am trying to find a way to implement "is_immediate".

```
static char arr[5];

void __attribute__((always_inline)) do_something(char * buf)
{
   if(is_immediate(buf) {

        // Argument is constant, can use immediate form

        asm volatile ("insn1 %0" : : "i"(buf));

   } else {

        // Argument is computed at runtime, use a register

        unsigned long tmp = (unsigned long)buf + 1;

        asm volatile("insn2 %0" : : "r"(tmp));

}


int main(void) 
{
   do_something(&arr);
}
```

At first impression __builtin_constant_p() seems like it is exactly the right bit of magic needed, except it does not work.

The reason is does not work is that while the address of the array will be known after the linker has placed the array in memory and chosen an address for it (and so it does fit the immediate constraint of the inline assembly), it is not known at **compile** time before the link.

So, what I am looking for is a way to ask - "is this variable fit to be an immediate value?" rather then "is this a constant expression?".

Comment: The types don't match up. Why is the argument `char *`, and not `char (*)[5]`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Please note I'm sending the address of arr as an argument, not arr itself.

Comment: @gby That's the point I think. Passing `arr` would be like passing `&arr[0]` = `char*` since array object gets converted during lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. OTOH `&arr` is already an rvalue of type `char(*)[5]` because `arr` is of type `char[5]`.

Comment: Also note that it's never possible to pass "array itself" in C; there are no rvalues of array type.

Comment: pointer values as immediates? I have never seen that. This might just be the reason why it doesn't work. Try the same with an integer and see if gcc is able to keep track of the fact that you fed a constant into the function.

Comment: @Kos I'm probably missing something obvious here, but an array name is a pointer to the first element by definition. arr is of type char *. &arr are the same thing.

Comment: @JensGustedt integer works just fine - because its value is not resolved in the link stage. The instruction I'm using is a custom instruction (I'm running on an Arc which is a synthesizable core) that takes an offset to an on chip SRAM.

Comment: @gby By *which* definition? That's an oversimplification often used when teaching C; kinda easier to explain than "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion". Arrays and pointers are distinct types. Check sizeof(arr) vs sizeof(&arr). Time to get a better book ;-)

Comment: tl;dr an array decays to a pointer-to-first-member when you use it as an rvalue, so when passing to a function or doing `arr[i]` or assigning it to a pointer, but not when doing `&arr` since `&` works on Lvalues.

Comment: @gby, so you say that for that custom instruction you can place an immediate that is interpreted as an address? You never finish to learn. So far I only have seen integer offsets as immediates that are added to an address that is hold in a register.

Comment: @Kos I would argue but I don't see how it is relevant to my question  - the result is the same whether I use arr or &arr so I'll just shut up now.

Comment: @JensGustedt that is basically what is happening with us with the exception that the base address is always aligned to a value that allows the custom instruction to take the address and just ignore enough MSB bits from the address so as to is at as an offset.

Comment: @gby: that's not true. `arr` is "the same as" `&arr[0]`, which is the address of the *first element*. By contrast, `&arr` is the address of the entire array. It's like the difference between saying that you "live in London" vs you "live in Britain". They're both correct, but the *type* is different.

Comment: @KerrekSB are they the same address? do you see any scenario where they will not be the same address? if one of them is known at link time, will the other one will not also be known?

Comment: @gby: the address is numerically the same, yes. But the types are different. A C++ object is uniquely determined by the pair "(type, address)". The array and its first element are different objects that live at the same address.

Comment: @KerrekSB somehow I guessed C++ would crop up in your argument at some point, however this is question about C :-) The do_something function takes a pointer to a char. In C, when we pass a pointer to char, we most often mean a pointer to a array of chars, which is exactly what was meant here. The intention is to get a pointer to the array, not the first element (even though the addresses are same). Therefore &arr is the right thing to do semantically, not just from an address point of view.

Comment: @gby: Ah, yes, but I believe the same is true for C. The fundamental object model of C++ is very strongly based on and compatible with that of C. I can double-check if you like. Your function parameter type is definitely mismatched.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a look on what is produced by my x86 compiler (where this insn doesn't make sense after all), it is here:

```
static char arr[5];

void __attribute__((always_inline)) do_something(char * buf)
{

        // Argument is constant, can use immediate form

        asm volatile ("insn1 %0" : : "r"(buf));

        unsigned long tmp = (unsigned long)buf;

        asm volatile("insn2 %0" : : "r"(tmp));

}


int main(void)
{
   char brr[5];
   do_something(arr);
   do_something(brr);
}
```

comes to

```
        .file   "inl.c"
        .text
.globl do_something
        .type   do_something, @function
do_something:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
#APP
# 8 "inl.c" 1
        insn1 %eax
# 0 "" 2
# 12 "inl.c" 1
        insn2 %eax
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        popl    %ebp
        ret
        .size   do_something, .-do_something
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    $arr, %eax
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $16, %esp
#APP
# 8 "inl.c" 1
        insn1 %eax
# 0 "" 2
# 12 "inl.c" 1
        insn2 %eax
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        leal    -5(%ebp), %eax
#APP
# 8 "inl.c" 1
        insn1 %eax
# 0 "" 2
# 12 "inl.c" 1
        insn2 %eax
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        leave
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .local  arr
        .comm   arr,5,4
        .ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 4.5.1 20101208 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 167585]"
        .section        .comment.SUSE.OPTs,"MS",@progbits,1
        .string "OSpwg"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

so I think it could make sense to be immediate as `$arr` is probably immediate (while `leal    -5(%ebp), %eax` isn't). Probably the said optimization just isn't supported.

But on the other hand,

```
            movl    $arr, %eax
            insn1 %eax
```

is not soo much worse than

```
            insn1 $arr
```

so that it is still acceptable, IMHO.

Comment: You are right that 2 instruction don't seem much compared to one for most uses. I happen to write very tight embedded and real time code where every cycle counts. I agree that this is not usually the case, though.

Comment: @gby You could add a macro which ends up having an `asm` statement with `"i"` - that should be more feasible than an inline one. You could keep the above as an alternative for being used in the case of calculated or stack-based addresses.

Comment: the inline function does not actually change anything - hand coding or using a macro does not change the behaviour

Comment: @gby mmm... with `#define do_something_with_imm(buf) do { asm volatile("insn2 %0" : : "i"(buf)); } while (0)` I got the desired behaviour. If I call it with the static `arr`, it works fine, if I call it with by `brr` lying on the stack, it fails. As intended.

Comment: if you put the asm volatile in an inline function with no if statement it will work just the same. An array on the stack does not have a constant address so no wonder it does not work.

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't work if I use the parameter of the function, even if I use an immediate in the calling function. With the macro, that works. 2. Of course, that's why I said "as intended" - it cannot be used as an immediate.

Comment: it will work if the compiler is told to do constant folding. Simply compiling with -O2 would do that, although there is a dedicated compiler flag if you do not wish to compile with other optimizations. Don't get me wrong - a macro work (or fails to work in my case) just as a inline function does. The problem will happen even if you simply manually copy and paste the content of the function to main.